# Compare value of foreach and checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have the a foreach loop that will split a text in the format of "1,2" into "1 2".

I am trying to compare each splited value with $rowCentral['tuitionAreaID'], when it is matched it the checkbox will be checked. I am able to achieve that, however, all my checkbox are duplicated.

```
    <?php
while($rowCentral=mysql_fetch_array($resultCentral))
    {
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
    //echo $my_Array.'<br>';  
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="centralArea[]" value="<?php echo $rowCentral['tuitionAreaID']?>" <?php if($my_Array == $rowCentral['tuitionAreaID']){echo "checked";}?>> <?php echo $rowCentral['tuitionAreaDesc']?><br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php       
    }
    ?>
```

This is the output of the code shown above (Each line are duplicated):

```
 Anson, Tanjong Pagar
 Anson, Tanjong Pagar
 Beach Road, High St, Hill St
 Beach Road, High St, Hill St
 Cairnhill, Newton, Orchard, Scotts Rd
 Cairnhill, Newton, Orchard, Scotts Rd
 Cecil, Chinatown, Marina, People's Park, Raffles Place
 Cecil, Chinatown, Marina, People's Park, Raffles Place
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: can you please format your code

Comment: The checkboxes are all duplicated two times

Comment: Yes because there mysql result have two row and you have added the foreach loop inside the while thats why it show 2 times

Comment: How should I change the code to prevent the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK what you want to achieve is this... You should CHECK if you need to set the checked property of your checkbox seperately, and test for that in your foreach and then only echo out the checkbox once.... Beware, that i have NOT tested my code..

```
<?php
while($rowCentral=mysql_fetch_array($resultCentral))
{       
    $checked = "";
    foreach($myArray as $my_Array)
    {
       if($my_Array == $rowCentral['tuitionAreaID'])
       {
         $checked = "checked";
       }           
    }
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='centralArea[]' value='".$rowCentral['tuitionAreaID']."' ".$checked.">".$rowCentral['tuitionAreaDesc']."<br>"
}
```